# How to a change my starting url to a custom url using parceljs

Tags: javascript, parceljs

```
 {
   "name": "openlayers",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "main": "index.js",
   "scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
   "start": "parcel  index.html",
   "build": "parcel build --public-url . index.html"
  },
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
 "app-root-path": "^2.2.1",
 "authenticate": "^0.1.5",
 "commonjs": "0.0.1",
 "config": "^3.2.4",
 "document-ready": "^2.0.2",
 "eazy-logger": "^3.0.2",
 "fs": "0.0.1-security",
 "jquery": "^3.4.1",
 "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
 "ol": "^5.3.3",
 "ol-contextmenu": "^3.3.2",
 "ol-hashed": "^2.0.0",
 "ol-layerswitcher": "^3.4.0",
 "proj4": "^2.6.0",
 "sidebar-v2": "^0.4.0",
 "simple-datatables": "^2.1.7",
 "simple-node-logger": "^18.12.23",
 "winston": "^3.2.1",
 "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^3.10.0"
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The current url is http://localhost:1234. I want this to be a custom url to authenticate with third party services that will only allow authentication to those urls.

Answer (score 0):

You use the `--host` option according to the [documentation](https://parceljs.org/cli.html#host).

So in your scripts section:

```
"start": "parcel serve index.html --host example.com",
```

Comment: does not work - TypeError: Cannot read property 'port' of null - even if it specify port "start": "parcel serve index.html --host example.com --port 1234",

Comment: If you have hot module reloading, then maybe try `--hmr-hostname` instead.

Comment: still not working says Server running at http://localhost:2420

Comment: You can also just put an entry into your hosts file for the domain you want and point it at 127.0.0.1. That should let you authenticate with third parties.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add domain to hosts file then do as said above.

```
"start": "parcel serve index.html --host example.com",
```